# ¿Cómo es el funcionamiento de __path__ para importar modulos distribuidos en diferentes directorios?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema relacionado con las importaciones de módulos que están separados en distintos directorios. Por lo cual me puse en la tarea de leer un poco sobre como solucionarlo, y esto me llevo a los `Paquetes en múltiples directorios` con [path](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/modules.html#paquetes-en-multiples-directorios) pero sigo sin entender bien dicha solución que me da la documentación de python.

Tengo la siguiente estructura en mi proyecto:

```
biblioteca/
|_ clases/
|  |_ __init__.py
|  |_ libro.py
|_ vistas/
|  |_ __init__.py
|  |_ agregarlibros.py
|  |_ menu.py
|_ main.py
```

El problema está en que manda las siguientes excepciones:

Esta excepción es cuando quiero importar el modulo `agregarlibros.py`, dentro de mi modulo `menu.py`

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'agregarlibros'

La siguiente excepcion sucede cuando importo `menu.py` a `agregarlibros.py`:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'menu'

Por otra parte las importaciones las hago de la siguiente forma:

Dentro de `menu.py`:

```
from agregarlibros import agregarLibros
```

Ahora dentro de `agregarlibros.py`:

```
from menu import menu
```

Por otra parte, también me surge el siguiente problema, cuando quiero importar el modulo de `libro.py`, que se encuentra en el directorio de `clases`, este no me deja, es más, ni en mi IDE me aparece la opción de poder importarlo, y me arroja está excepción:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clases'

Antes de terminar, aclaro que desde la clase `main.py`, solo importo el modulo de `menu.py`, por el momento no me marca ninguna excepción, pero así lo importo:

```
from vistas.menu import menu
```

Anexo las clases las cuales "interactúan" entre ellas:

El `main.py:`

```
from vistas.menu import menu

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu()
```

El `menu.py:`

```
import os
#from agregarlibros import agregarLibros -> Genera error
from vistas import agregarlibros # Solución del error


def menu():
    menu = ("\n1. Agregar libros. \
            \n2. Buscar libros. \
            \n3. Actualizar bibloteca. \
            \n4. Volver al menú. \
            \n5. Limpiar pantalla. \
            \n6. Salir.\n")

    while True:
        try:
            print("{:*^50}".format("Menú de la Biblioteca"))
            print(menu)
            opcion = int(input("Eliga una opción: "))

            if opcion == 1:
                os.system("clear")
                agregarlibros.agregarLibros() #Aquí llamo a la función agregarLibros() del modulo agregarlibros
            elif opcion == 2:
                pass
            elif opcion == 3:
                pass
            elif opcion == 4:
                print(menu)
            elif opcion == 5:
                print(menu)
                os.system("clear")
            elif opcion == 6:
                print("\n¡¡ Hasta Pronto !!")
                break
            else:
                os.system("clear")
                print("\nADVERTENCIA: Por favor elija una opción del menú\n")

        except ValueError:
            os.system("clear")
            print("\nADVERTENCIA: Por favor un dígito.\n")
```

Y `agregarlibros.py:`

```
import os
#from menu import menu  -> Genera error  
from clases.libro import Libro

#Módulo con funciones del menú principal
def agregarLibros():
    biblioteca = []
    salida = True

    while True:
        print("{:*^60}".format("Bienvenido, formulario para agregar libros."))

        nombre = input("\nIngrese el nombre: ")
        codigo_referencia = input("Ingrese el ISBN: ")
        autor = input("Ingrese el autor(@): ")
        editorial = input("Ingrese la editorial: ")
        fecha_lanzamiento = input("Ingrese la fecha de lanzamiento: ")

        libros = Libro(nombre, codigo_referencia, autor, editorial, fecha_lanzamiento)
        biblioteca.append(libros)

        while True:
            opcion = input("¿Desea registrar otro libro? [Y/N]: ").upper()

            if opcion == "Y":
                os.system("clear")
                break
            elif opcion == "N":
                salida = False
                break
            else:
                print("Por favor ingrese una de las dos opciones.")

        if salida == False:
            os.system("clear")
            menu.menu() # -> Genera error
             #La solución es eliminar la importación que genera error y quitar menu.menu() ya que con el break sale del ciclo y "automaticamente vuelve al menu sin hacer la recursión"
            break
```

Quisiera saber cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo, y si pueden orientarme con respecto a uso de `__path__`. No se si sea algo relevante, pero estoy desarrollando desde `Ubuntu 17.10` en el `IDE Atom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que quieras llamar a `menu.menu` desde tu `main.py` tal como haces basta con hacer lo siguiente:

- En ***menu.py***:

  ```
  from vistas import agregarlibros
  ```

  ó:

  ```
  from . import agregarlibros
  ```

  Llama a la función `agregarLibros` mediante `agregarlibros.agregarLibros()`
- En ***agregarlibros.py***:

  ```
  from vistas import menu
  ```

  ó:

  ```
  from . import menu
  ```

  Llama a la función `menu` mediante `menu.menu()`

**Estas realizando lo que se llama un import circular o cíclico** además de usar recursión mediante dos funciones que se llaman una a la otra. Ten mucho cuidado con ello, importando de esta forma y con el código que muestras no tendrás problemas en principio, pero si intentas importar directamente la función o llamas a la función importada desde el espacio global vas a tener un error de importación.

Por norma general es mejor evitar los imports circulares (y la recursión si es posible) refactorizando el código. Para ello sería necesario conocer como usas la variable `biblioteca`.

---

En cuanto al atributo  `__path__`, se inicializa para ser una lista que contiene el nombre del directorio que contiene al módulo `__init__.py` del paquete antes de que se ejecute el código del propio archivo.

Existen varios casos en los que puede ser útil como en algunos imports condicionales,  pero es comúnmente usado para forzar al intérprete a que busque módulos que pertenecen al paquete pero que se encuentran en directorios diferentes al que contiene el `__init__.py`. A modo de ejemplo, si tenemos algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y queremos acceder e importar ***moduloB.py*** como hacemos con ***moduloA.py***, podemos hacer lo siguiente en el ***__init__.py***:

```
import os


__path__.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "subpackage"))
```

`subpackage` podría estar en realidad en cualquier directorio que pueda ser accesible.  Lo anterior permite importar ***moduloB*** sin "pasar" por ***subpackage***:

```
from package import moduloB
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, entiendo lo que me dices con respecto a evitar esos ciclos, ahora he "mejorado" esa parte. Por otra parte, todavía no puedo solucionar el problema de importación de un modulo de otro directorio, es decir, no puedo importar `libro.py` dentro de mi `agregarlibros.py`, me sigue saliendo que no esta definida la importación. El`__path__` lo he agregado en ambos`__init__.py `de cada directorio, pero sigo sin obtener resultado.

Comment: @CamiloJc eso solo debería pasar si intentas ejecutar el módulo directamente, si ejecutas el main.py el código fucniona, lo acabo de probar. Eso si, para el nombre de archivos que dices tener debe ser `from vistas import agregarlibros` y no `from vista import agregarLibros` y `from vistas import menu` en vez de `from vista import menu`. Con esto el `__init__.py` puede estar vacío.

Comment: Entiendo, si no me había fijado en ello, ya lo he editado, gracias por tu ayuda, me estaba confundiendo, pero lo he aclarado, de nuevo gracias. Saludos !!!